# Kivy PyInstaller Crashing OSX

Tags: python, macos, kivy, pyinstaller

I am trying to package a Kivy app for OS X using PyInstaller (following these instructions: [from Kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-osx.html)

However, the resulting .dmg that is created crashes immediately after it opens. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here are the commands I am running:

```
pyinstaller -y --clean --windowed --name myapp --exclude-module _tkinte --exclude-module Tkinter --exclude-module enchant --exclude-module twisted /usr/Desktop/myappp/main.py
```

Then I add the following line to COLLECT inside the .spec file created by the previous command:

```
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('/usr/Desktop/myapp/'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='myapp')
```

Then:

```
$ pyinstaller -y --clean --windowed touchtracer.spec
```

And

```
$ pushd dist
$ hdiutil create ./Touchtracer.dmg -srcfolder touchtracer.app -ov
$ popd
```

Comment: can u type ur pyinstaller line of code used or try to complle and then dmg to open up with the console, im not sure hw thats done on a OS X but on windows it wud be `pyinstaller -c -F filename.py`

Comment: pyinstaller -y --clean --windowed --name touchtracer \
  --exclude-module _tkinter \
  --exclude-module Tkinter \
  --exclude-module enchant \
  --exclude-module twisted \
  /usr/local/share/kivy-examples/demo/touchtracer/main.py is the line I used

Comment: if u open it up in the console, then u can have a look at the error that comes up, so find a way to make a dmg that opens in console and not `--windowed`

Comment: @CoolCloud What do you mean by opening in console? Like as an .exe?

Comment: I ran hdiutil attach /path/to/dmg and got no errors.

Comment: oh i see, im not sure why tho